# Fat Free Framework configurations on a subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, fat-free-framework

I am trying to deploy an Fat Free Framework app on a subdomain. It worked fine on my local server but I get a blank page on deploying it on a sub-domain on a live site. I believe I somehow got my configurations (`.htaccess`, config/routes) wrong but I've tried several but can't get it to work. My configs are:

**.routes** file

```
[routes]
GET /games/@gameid/@move = WebPage->getgames
```

**.config** file

```
[globals]
AUTOLOAD = app/;third_party/;third_party/phpQuery/
DEBUG = 0
UI = views/
ENCODING = utf-8
LOGS= tmp/cache/
```

**.htaccess** file

```
#mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]

#Hotlinking Protection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?subdomain.domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpg|gif|png|bmp|mp4|3gp|m4a|m4r|aac|mp3|ogg|wave)$ - [F]

#PHP code in HTML file
AddType fcgid-script .php .htm .html .phtml
```

I'm on  PHP Version 5.3.28 Apache 2.3.7

Folder Structure

subdomain.domain.com (subdomain folder)

- .htaccess file
- index.php file
- app folder
- db folder
- views folder
- third_party folder
- tmp folder

On my local server I have .htaccess file like this

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Like I said earlier it works on my local server (on a virtual host, not a subdomain). I don't know if I'm answering your question correctly, but I've tried to reproduce the folder structure above. The only correction being that my subdomain folder is named subdomain.domain.com on my web host's files

Comment: Okay. On my local host I access the url http://games.loc/games/01test20140322/1 and it works. I have edited the question to show the .htaccess file. The folder structure is the same, the only difference is that on the live site I installed F3 on a subdomain. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems incorrect:

```
RewriteBase /subdomain.domain.com
```

I would change it to simply be this:

```
RewriteBase /
```

The reason being is `RewriteBase` only refers to the URL base of the server itself and not anything further “to the left” of that. Meaning if this is your main site URL:

> `http://subdomain.domain.com`

Setting a `RewriteBase /subdomain.domain.com` would mean that the rules would only act on the URL of :

> `http://subdomain.domain.com/subdomain.domain.com`

And to make it a bit clearer, one would only adjust `RewriteBase /` (an then the corresponding `RewriteRule`) if the code is running on a path “to the right” of the base URL. So let’s say you installed it in the directory `mycoolapp/` and you wanted that to be accessible like this:

```
RewriteBase /mycoolapp/
```

And then you would have to adjust the `RewriteRule` for the `index.php` like this:

```
RewriteRule . /mycoolapp/index.php [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT:** Based on you providing the `.htaccess` for your local setup, you have this for your `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

But on your subdomain setup you have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Why the radical difference? Just use the `mod_rewrite` stuff that works from your local setup.  Specifically get rid of this line on your subdomain setup:

```
RewriteBase /
```

And change this line:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
```

To be this:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

So the final subdomain `.htaccess` should have this:

```
#mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]

#Hotlinking Protection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?subdomain.domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpg|gif|png|bmp|mp4|3gp|m4a|m4r|aac|mp3|ogg|wave)$ - [F]

#PHP code in HTML file
AddType fcgid-script .php .htm .html .phtml
```

Comment: Ok. I edited the .htaccess file like you recommend but still get a blank page. I'm trying to access http://subdomain.domain.com/games/01test20140322/1 based on the routes described above. Thanks

Comment: Absolute base?? I'm a little confused about that term, but I'm trying to access subdomain.domain.com/games/01test20140322/1 like I said above. The /01test20140322 routes to the 'gameid' and /1 is the 'move' as specified in the routes file.

Comment: Working fine now. Posted the reason for the earlier problem as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was caused by a php error and because I had show errors turned off, I couldn't see it. It was caught by the support staff of my web host after I uploaded a fresh install of the app and got

> Internal Server Error
>   Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Specifically my web hosting support staff said it had to do with PHP array dereferencing. I quote partly below

> ..it looks like a part of your scripts are using array dereferencing
>   which works on PHP 5.4+, and..

So we switched to PHP 5.4+ and bam everything went into place.

BTW I used the following .htaccess

```
#mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

No stress, no fuss.